# Add class to the same TD on next TR

Tags: javascript, html

I want to achieve this.

If the `td` has the class and `today`, i want to add the same classes to the same `td` on the next `tr`, on this example is the day 12.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">2</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">3</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">4</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day active today">5</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">6</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">7</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">9</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">10</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">11</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day">12</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">13</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">14</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "if the `td` has the class and `today`" - are you missing a word between "class" and "and"?

Comment: I guess missing word is "active" =)

Comment: I meant, if `td` has class `today`

Comment: how you are apply class "Today" on first td? the same logic cam be applied on all other tds. or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Find the `.today` element
- Find its index within its parent
- find the other tr elements (everything after the first one?)
- use the index to get that child `td`
- apply whatever class you want to it

```js
var todayElem = document.querySelector(".today");
var todayIndex = [...todayElem.parentNode.children].indexOf(todayElem)
console.log(todayIndex)

var trElems = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
[...trElems].slice(1).forEach(tr => {
  tr.querySelectorAll("td")[todayIndex].classList.add("active")
});
```

```css
.today{
  background-color:red
}

.active{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">2</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">3</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">4</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day active today">5</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">6</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">7</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">9</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">10</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">11</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day">12</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">13</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">14</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nice and short! beware though: indexOf may yield different results depending on wether there are textnodes in between the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// find index of today element
var index = null;
document.querySelectorAll('.today').forEach(function(td) {
   index = 0;
   while ((td = td.previousSibling) != null) {
      if (td.tagName != "TD") continue;
      index += 1;
   }
});

// add the class for each row
document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(tr) {
   tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(td, i) {
      if (i != index) return;
      td.classList.add("today");
   });
});
```

I think you should have a look at the `colgroup` feature here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup - usually that is an easier way to get what you are aiming for.

Answer (score -1):

```js
//select first row
var firstTr = $("table tr").first();
// find index of colum
var pos = firstTr.find(".day.today").index();
//select next row and apply class today on specific td
firstTr.next().find("td:eq("+pos+")").addClass("today");
```

```css
.today{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">2</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">3</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">4</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day active today">5</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">6</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">7</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/02/2020" class="day weekend">9</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/03/2020" class="day">10</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/04/2020" class="day">11</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/05/2020" class="day">12</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/06/2020" class="day">13</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/07/2020" class="day">14</td>
    <td data-action="selectDay" data-day="02/08/2020" class="day weekend">15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```